# When we use d3 with rails 6 with webpack it thwos below error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, d3.js, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Using ruby 2.7.3
Rails 6.1.3

I am using d3 but it throws the below error on console -

```
TypeError: setting getter-only property "format" using
Ie https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js:2
<anonymous> https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js:2
<anonymous> https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js:2
<anonymous> https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js:2
```

On the view page, I have added the below code -

```
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js">
   </script>
   <%= javascript_pack_tag "home/index" %>
```

Below line added app/javascript/packs/application.js -

```
 import * as d3 from "d3"
 window.d3 = d3
```

Please give suggestions on these.

Comment: Importing the script like this already sets the object `d3` on `window`. You don't need to do this at all. You can either remove the `window.d3 = d3;` or include `d3.js` in your webpack bundle and keep the `import`